# Is it possible for me to apply changes

Tags: git, git-bash

Here's the back story:

Last Friday, after doing some work on `/some-branch`, I did a `git stash save`, checked out `/another-branch`, then a `git stash pop` and everything went to Hell. I closed the terminal after trying unsuccessfully to recover the changes I had stashed. Now I'm trying to do that again.

From what I understand, those changes I stashed, if they weren't garbage-collected, correspond to hash values of a `dangling blob` that I see when I run `git fsck --no-reflog`. So how can I figure out which one corresponds to that stash last Friday, and how do I bring it back to life. Or can't I, and I've lost all those changes? :(

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly happened when you say "then a git stash pop and everything went to Hell" ? Did you get conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git status` from both `/some-branch` and `/another-branch` to make sure the changes aren't in your working directory?

If that proves unfruitful, try `git fsck --unreachable` from both branches as well. The changes COULD be gone, but only if you've done something like a `reset` or a `pull` before stashing your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for a dangling commit, not a dangling blob.  If you've run `git fsck` and have a (smallish) set of dangling commits,  you can inspect each one using `git cat-file -p <commit id>` and see if any of those commits look like the one you stashed.  If you have a lot of commits, that could be a lot of work.

Another option is, if you still have any stashes remaining, run `git reflog refs/stash` to see the history of the stashes you've created.  Unfortunately those logs are deleted once you pop your last stash, so you may not have it available.

Once you've found the correct commit id using one of the methods above, you can then either `git checkout <commit id>` or `git branch newbranch <commit id>` to either checkout the commit directly, or create a new branch pointing at that commit.